# SAS Date Functions: Quarterly Equivelant of Day Function

Tags: sas

I often use the `day` function in order to control date parameters within queries.

With the data step below I can call the beginning of the current month `&bom` based on whether or not the day of the month is `le` to the 8th of each month (in which that case we want `&bom` set to the 1st of the previous month), otherwise set `&bom` to the 1st of the current month.

```
data _null_;
call symput('current'," '" || put(intnx('day',today(),0),yymmdd10.) || "'");
call symput('bom'," '" || put(intnx('month',today(),0,'b'),yymmdd10.) || "'");
call symput('end'," '" || put(intnx('day',today(),-8,'e'),yymmdd10.) || "'");
if day(today()) le 8 then do;
call symput('bom'," '" || put(intnx('month',today(),-1,'b'),yymmdd10.) || "'");
end;
run;

%put &bom &end &current;

262    %put &bom &end &current;
'2015-12-01'  '2015-12-30'  '2016-01-07'
```

It would seem simple to apply this logic to a "quarterly type" condition. So - If the (sequential) day of the quarter is less than 8 days after the last day of the quarter, your `&boq` (beginning of quarter) value would be the first day of the LAST quarter`'2015-10-01'`, but the `qtr` function creates values based on the quarter `1-4`, not the "number" representing the sequential day of the quarter.

Is there a function that can operate on the number of days on a quarterly level, much like the `day` function operating on a monthly level?

My initial attempt was wrapping functions...no success...

```
qtr_day = day(qtr(today()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use SAS date, since SAS dates are numbers, so you can find the date boundary and add/subtract 8 as desired to increment. Or you can nest intnx functions on a date. To have the date display as a quarter use a quarter format to display the date.

```
date_qtr_boundary = intnx('quarter', today(), 0, 'e') + 8;
```

Then you can compare your dates to the boundary value rather than the number 8. I'm having a hard time following exactly what you want to determine, but if you post some sample data and expected output, I (or someone else) can provide more details.

Comment: I think you are understanding my concept. Lets use todays date (8th) to clarify/confirm. Since it is <= to the 8th day of the quarter, I need to create a mac. var. &boq to represent the first day of the previous quarter ('2015-10-01'), but if I execute the job tomorrow (9th), I need it to create mac. var. &boq for the first day of the current quarter ('2016-01-01'). I believe that you have given me a solution by clarifying the date of where the boundary of the quarter (beginning or end) occur, and operating off of that: correct?

Comment: `DATA _NULL_;
CALL SYMPUT('BOQ'," '" || PUT(INTNX('QUARTER',TODAY(),0,'B'),YYMMDD10.) || "'");
IF TODAY() <= INTNX('QUARTER', TODAY(), 0, 'E') + 8 THEN DO;
 CALL SYMPUT('BOQ'," '" || PUT(INTNX('QUARTER',TODAY(),-1,'B'),YYMMDD10.) || "'");
END;
RUN;
%PUT &BOQ;`                                                                                                        This seemed to do the trick (producing value of '2015-10-01').